# Части в Шаблонах Django типо как в React

Tags: html, django, django-template

У меня есть два файла html и обоих есть одинаковые блоки с классом product.

```html
<!-- shop/templates/favorite.html, shop/templates/index.html -->
...
<div class="product">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <div class="product__image-title">
            <img class="product__image" src="{{ product.first_image }}" alt="">
            <h5 class="product__title">
              <a class="lnk" href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ phone.name }}</a>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <h4 class="product__price">{{ product.get_price }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="product__buttons">
          <div>
            <button type="submit" class=" btn rounded-0" data-to="{{product.to_favorite_url}}">
              <i
                class="bi bi-heart{% if phone in user.profile.favorite_products.all %}-fill text-primary{% endif %}"></i>
            </button>

            <button type="submit" class="btn rounded-0" data-to="{{product.to_compare_url}}">
              <i class="bi bi-filter {% if product in user.profile.compare_products.all %}text-primary{% endif %}"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <button class="btn rounded-0 btn-primary">
            <i class="bi bi-basket"></i>
          </button>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Можно ли сделать так что-бы объявить этот блок в отдельный html файл? И я мог вставить в favorite.html и index.html этот файл с контекстом?

```py
class Product:
  ...
  def as_card(self) -> str:
    # нужен функция типо render_part
    return render_part('product_card.html', {
               'product': self
              })
  ...
```

```html
<!-- shop/templates/favorite.html, shop/templates/index.html -->
{% autoescape off %}
{{product.as_card}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Тег include позволяет добавить в один шаблон другой шаблон. Контекст захватывается из родительского контекста

Comment: @Vlados Спасибо!